# Having incompatible issue when build LSTM VAE model

Tags: python, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I try to build a `VAE` `LSTM` model with `keras`. Input shape is `(sample_number,20,31)`

While, there are some incompatible issue happening.

I'm not sure which part of my code being wrong, forgive me for posting all of them.

My import:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.objectives import mse
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, LSTM, TimeDistributed, RepeatVector, Input, Lambda
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
```

Firstly, I create a normal distribution sampling function.

```
def sampling(args):
     z_mean, z_log_var = args
     batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
     dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
     epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch,dim))
     return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

Then build the encoder and decoder

```
"======Encoer====="
inputs = Input(shape=(20,31,), name='encoder_input')
x = LSTM(30,activation='relu',return_sequences=True) (inputs)
x = LSTM(60,activation='relu') (x)
z_mean = Dense(60, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = Dense(60, name='z_log_var')(x)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(60,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
z = RepeatVector(20)(z)
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')

"=====Decoder======="
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(20,60), name='z_sampling')
x_2 = LSTM(60, activation='relu',return_sequences= True)(latent_inputs)
x_2 = LSTM(31, activation='relu')(x_2)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, x_2, name='decoder')
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Finally customize the loss function and fit the model

```
reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss) 
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
vae.fit(train,validation_data=(val,None),epochs=100)
```

It will get this error, but I can't find anywhere the shape is 
 `[32,31]` or `[32,20,31]`:

```
    InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1326     try:
-> 1327       return fn(*args)
   1328     except errors.OpError as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1305                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1306                                    status, run_metadata)
   1307 

~\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,20] vs. [32]
```

Appreciate for your answer.

Comment: It's very probably in the **missing** `return_sequences=True`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error issue become, Incompatible shapes: [32,20] vs. [32], when I add return_sequence, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input shape for the encoder is `(32,20,31)` here `32` is default `batch_size` and output of decoder is `(32,31)` and `mse` function is complaining about both of the shapes.

Problem should be resolved by replacing:
`x_2 = LSTM(31, activation='relu')(x_2)` by
`x_2 = LSTM(31, activation='relu',return_sequences=True)(x_2)`

P.S.: Also you can try running `encoder.summary()` and `decoder.summary()` to get the shape of each layer.

Edit: 
           `kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)` to `kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to add return_sequences, while it comes up another error, Incompatible shapes: [32,20] vs. [32]. I can't find any shape being [32,20] or [32] when Model.summary(). That's my primary problem.

Comment: Okay. Can you please provide full error stack trace?

Comment: It seems the problem is in addition of `reconstruction_loss` and `kl_loss`. I changed `kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)` to `kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss)` and seems to run on redundant training data. But I'm not sure if the change will affect your loss function.

Comment: @ Vitrioil , that works !!! Problem caused by axis of K.sum. Really appreciate for your answering.